# Enable Facebook comments on site without a Facebook app / app ID?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

From what I can read om Facebook Dev Docs this is how I add the comment box on my web site:

```
//In HTML Header
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>

//Where I want my comments to show
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?=curPageURL()?>" data-num-posts="5" data-width="944"></div>
```

And... If I want to add admins to the comments I can add this to my meta-data:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="jamie.telin"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

But am I correct as to this being the only way, or atleast that I must have created an Facebook App to use Facebook Comments? *If I am not misstaken, this wasn't required before.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need an App ID. In order to have an App ID, you have to create a Facebook App.

Comment: But I must have an App ID to use FB Comments?

Comment: As you are accessing Facebook API, you have to create a Facebook App.

Comment: Ok, then I know, thanks. I am atleast not doing it for no reason then. Still it's a stupid move from Facebook forcing me to create an App for such a standard tool, in my opinion. ^^

Comment: Facebook just wants to filter out unauthorized access to their API. Reasonable.

Comment: To use any of Facebook's social plug-ins, it is *not* required to have an `AppId`.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I have created this functionality in the past; without an APP ID. Using a premium wordpress theme where it was included; how could it work without an App ID then -- and not now?

Comment: creating a Facebook App is free. Go create one (and obtain an App ID)

Comment: But the appid is linked to a individual real users account - many people would like this to be generic.

Answer (score 2):

No, FB social plugins doesn't need an App ID - they are rendered into an iframe originating from facebook.com, so FB login status and cookies as accessible to them.

Make sure that you set `status: false` and `cookie: false` in your FB.init() call. Do not provide any appId param.

Comment: AppId is included as part of javascript sdk.. see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ - so isn't it compulsory?

Comment: @Jasper asking myself this question again and again since three or four years. For me, comments still work when using the default snippet and just removing &appId=xxxxxxx. I guess you will not have any stats on users using your comments, when not giving an appId...but that might be ok for many uses...like "just gimme comments, I dont want your stats..."

Answer (score 1):

You can Add it without any app or app ID Too easy 
The easiest comment box to implement would be using Facebook comments. You could take a look at this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: This is accurate. You don't need a Facebook id. to use comments.