# How should a web developer obtain an facebook APP_ID not to use same ID for different sites?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I found an old post, but one that does not solve my issue clearly.
[Enable Facebook comments on site without a Facebook app / app ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615497/enable-facebook-comments-on-site-without-a-facebook-app-app-id)

I'm a web developer I build pages and embed facebook plugins. Not all, but some (like facebook Comments https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/ ) plugins require you to chose an App to use its APP_ID.

Should a developer use his own account to create apps. Or create different account for each client? Facebook seems to require one of those.

Preferable way, would be to not add any APP_ID to plugin. But, is this possible? If yes, then how?
What would be "good practice" to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using an `App-id`- you **can't** integrate these facebook social plugins.

The developer can use his own account for the app creation, then any time later he can add/remove administrator. So, before submitting to the client, just add the client as admin and remove yourself as the admin. See here how to do it-

[image]

**But** of course the client must have verified his/her account, else you'll not  be able to add -

[image]

But dont worry not a big deal, just tell your client to go [**here**](https://www.facebook.com/help/verify) and verify the account. Simple enough?

Comment: Especially if somone says: "I don't have FB account and I dont want to". :). That means for some apps i will have to be admin forever - hehe. That's my pain.
It's still easier not to ask for somone's creditentials.

Comment: Think this is best answer i can get :). Shame Facebook made it requirement. (They too big, They shall hopefully fall :>)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No. App id is required. And It seems both the Facebook and Twitter App ID pages assume the developer is the same person as the Facebook / Twitter account holder. So it would be better if the client creates an app id from his/her account to use for their particular app.

Comment: Problem is. some clients will do this. Some will totally have no idea what to do. That's why they hire me. There should be a way. Stupid facebook.